# android timer handler java

Tags: java, android, timer, handler

I want to insert values in my data base using timer i started with using the timer to display a msg and it work but when i added the call of th function that insert values just the msg display and no data inserted!! here is my code

```
public class TimertestActivity extends Activity {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            afficher();

        }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

      @Override   
      public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {   
        super.onCreate(icicle);   
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
        lat = 123456.98;
        lng = 321654.78;
        runnable.run();
      }   

     public void afficher()
      {
          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                     "lat" +lat+ "lng" +lng,
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          insertvalues(lat, lng);
          handler.postDelayed(runnable, 25000);
      }
     public void insertvalues(double lat, double lng){

          //http post c à d envoi des données
          try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new   
                HttpPost("http://www.pizza-paris.com/clic/marwa/test/form.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }       
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you put a debug point at the HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); line to step through the calls to see exactly whats happening? Do you have internet permissions requested in your manifest?

Comment: Good thnx i forgot inetrnet permission! thanks jack! some time we do th hard and forget some details that can change all!! thnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add internet permissions to his manifest. It's always the simple things.

Please read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) link for information on permissions.

The correct format would be:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```